# Increase logging level in Apache Samza

Tags: logging, clojure, apache-samza

I'm trying to change the logging level for Apache Samza so I can get `debug` statements; the default is `info`. More specifically, I'm trying to get [this debug statement](https://github.com/apache/samza/blob/master/samza-kafka/src/main/scala/org/apache/samza/system/kafka/BrokerProxy.scala#L159) to show up.

I'm using Samza in a Clojure project. What is the best way to do this? The [Samza Logging](https://samza.apache.org/learn/documentation/0.7.0/jobs/logging.html) page does not given any useful information.

Answer (score 2):

The Samza Logging page provides sufficient information. In more direct terms, the steps are:

1. in project.clj, include the slf4j-log4j dependency
2. in project.clj, define a jvm system property called "log4j.configuration" that points to a log4j xml configuration file
3. in the log4j xml configuration file, define the root log level to be "debug"

Which of those things have been done?

Comment: Step 1 has bee done. I didn't know about JVM system property for `project.clj`; I'll try that.